# Output of pie chart - R programming

Tags: r, pie-chart

I have written the following code, however on running it on Rstudio, I get the following -->

```
**null device 
          1**
```

How do I resolve?

```
x <- c(21, 62, 10, 53)
labels <- c("London", "New York", "Singapore", "Mumbai")


png(file = "city_title_colours.jpg")


pie(x, labels, main = "City pie chart", col = rainbow(length(x)))

dev.off()
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong. This is the output that should be expected from `dev.off()`. It is the number and name of the device that is the new current device that will be used when you create a plot.

Comment: What's your intended output? If you want to view the chart in your environment, don't write it to file.

Comment: Your plot will have been stored in the file `city_title_colours.jpg`.

Comment: `browseURL('city_title_colours.jpg')`